# PyCharm Jupyter notebook : Add Jupyter to the interpreter of the current project

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I have a new project in PyCharm under it the project, I create a jupyter notebook
but when I run it I keep getting this error

```
Add Jupyter to the interpreter of the current project.
```

I cant figure out what to do, I have reset the

> Project Interpretor
>   But no use

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to install jupyter for the project interpreter or the virtualenv that you use:

`pip install jupyter`

PyCharm support for the Jupyter Notebook is shaky IMO. You will probably need to restart it, and respond to dialog windows trying to connect to the default Notebook server location, localhost:8888. On my machine, canceling that request to connect strangely helps to finally see the output of the cells within PyCharm.